# Can't get certain clip-paths to work

Tags: css, mask, masking, clip

I know this is super simple, but I can't seem to get a simple ellipse masking to work in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/foomarks/m5272/3/

```
img {
position: absolute;
-webkit-clip-path: ellipse(200px,200px,50px,100px);    
}
```

Anyone have any hints as to what I'm doing incorrectly.

(My understanding is that it's not necessary to create SVG paths for basic shapes: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for shapes has changed at the beginning of this year.

It's:

- `inset(<margin>[ round <border-radius>]?)` for rectangle - [**demo**](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/bLlfa) (`<margin>` and `<border-radius>` values are exactly like the values for the `margin` and `border-radius` properties respectively)
- `circle([<radius>]?[ at <position>]?)` for circle - [**demo**](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/wqjem) (similar to how you specify radial gradients)
- `ellipse([<radius>{1,2}]?[ at <position>]?)` for ellipse - [**demo**](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/hrqiF)
- the same for generic polygon

The new syntax for shapes is supported by Chrome 34+, Opera 21+ and Safari 8.

Also, the `clip` property mentioned in that article has been deprecated.